# \texttt and \alltt produce brackets in PDF that can't be copied

Tags: pdftex, packages, pdf, acrobat

The code

```
\texttt{ \{k\!,0\!,dim\} }
```

and

```
\begin{alltt} \{k\!,0\!,dim\} \end{alltt}
```

both produce a PDF in which copying that text and pasting it elsewhere (such as a text editor or Mathematica or internet browser) produces `fk, 0, dimg`. This is incredibly disadvantagous when you have a larger amount of code to be copied somewhere. How can I remedy this problem?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,alltt}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt} \{k\!,0\!,dim\} \end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\texttt` or `alltt`, could you try `\verb+ ... +`, where the paired `+` can be any character that isn't in the verbatim string.  (I'm not able to test just now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use T1-encoding. With the default OT1 the braces are taken from the math font:

```
\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,alltt}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt} \{k\!,0\!,dim\} \end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

### with T1:

[image]

### with OT1:

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you!